# Grunt qunit is failing

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-qunit

I have configured my qunit task is grunt as below:

```
 // Unit Test Configuration
    qunit: {
        ac: {
            files: ['test/**/*.html']
        }
    }
    grunt.registerTask('ac', ['jshint:ac', 'qunit:ac']);
```

jsHint is running fine. But with qunit i am getting error:

Running "qunit:ac" (qunit) task
Warning: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'src'

Answer (score 7):

Change `files: ['test/**/*.html']` to `src: ['test/**/*.html']`. The `files` property is intended for multiple `src/dest` pairings. See http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#files-object-format

For example:

```
qunit: {
  ac: {
    files: [{
      src: ['test/**/*.html']
    }, {
      src: ['test2/**/*.html']
    }]
  }
}
```

A more simple config if you just want `test/**/*.html` would be:

```
qunit: {
  ac: ['test/**/*.html']
}
```

Comment: I just changed ac: ac: ['test/**/*.html']['test/unittest/unit1/*.html'] and now it is working. Thanks.